# Getting this in log and execution freezes - WARN - detach - immutable map: myrespo.my_industries[227].department in Karate v1.2.0

Tags: karate

I am calling another feature in Background and using that output json in the Scenario Outline Examples.

But, when I run it in parallel using Runner, I see following message in log and the execution freezes

[pool-3-thread-1] 04-Jun-2022 17:40:22.331 WARN  - detach - immutable map: myrespo.my_industries[227].department

It runs perfectly fine when I run the feature file directly in Intellij

Comment: What i found id that when I use only 1 thread for parallel Execution, it works all fine But when I increase the number of Threads, it fails and there are lot of such attach,detach kind of warnings in the log. Can somebody please provide a hint / solution please?

Comment: Any help in this is appreciated.